# Front page link token in full HTML?

Tags: tokens, uri

When Im using the full html input format. Is there a way I can use some code to print the url of the front page of my site, so If I were to migrate the site it would still work?

I could do this with pathlogic but im wondering if there is a php type value that full html would use?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="/">Front page</a>
```

But this doesn't respect the base folder. E.g. if your Drupal installation path looks like http://example.com/drupal_site/, this won't help you, because link will lead to http://example.com/.